# performance problem on download with vlan and bridge

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet, performance, bridge

I have a weird performance problem with a Rpi with Raspbian 11: when I take a speedtest with Ookla CLI I obtain download speed no better than 30Mbs but upload speed over 60Mbs and I know it's not a internet issue.

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces.d/bridge content:

```
 # interfaccia eth0 
 auto eth0 
 iface eth0 inet manual

 # VLAN 1
 #auto eth0.1
 #iface eth0.1 inet manual

 # VLAN 2 
 auto eth0.2 
 iface eth0.2 inet manual
          hwaddress ether xx:xx:xx:xx:9B:25

 # Bridge br0 
 auto br0 
 iface br0 inet manual
        bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_waitport 0
        bridge_fd 0
```

my **ip a**

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:25:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:70:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

6: eth0.2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:9b:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 192.168.0.212/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0.2 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:25:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 192.168.1.212/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute br0 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

VLAN1 is the PVID default VLAN used by br0 which is connected to my internal LAN and eth0.2 uses VLAN2 which is connected to the internet gateway (ZTE MC888) via a managed switch port (tagged VLAN2 and PVID1).

When I'm directly connected via cable (with a W10 client) to the ethernet port of the same gateway I see dl speed of 300mb/s but using the above configuration over a Zyxel managed switch I read around a tenth of that speed!! and this slow performance affects only communications over VLAN2.

could someone nudge me on the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: What Pi? What OS? Why are you using ancient Debian networking?

Comment: it's a RPi 3B+ with the official Raspbian OS (bullseye) and I'm using the default networking embedded with this os; ifupdown and dhcpcd; anyways I found the solution: it was disabled the "flow control" on the switch between the Pi and the router. the speed negotiated (1Gbps FD) was too much for the Pi bus and a lot of packets requested retransmission. I just overlooked this problem because it's  the first time I encounter it on my home network. Pis are useful also for solving "exotic" problems ;)